# Creating a fluid row with Foundation 6 scss

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation-6

What is the proper way to create a [fluid row](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#fluid-row) with Foundation 6 and scss? Currently I am doing it by setting `$width: none`, but I'm not sure if this is correct:

```
.topBanner {
  @include grid-row($width: none);
  background-color: $secondary-color;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The produced CSS from this is:

```
.topBanner {
    max-width: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #4990E2;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: What CSS does this produce for `.topBanner`?

Comment: I added the produced CSS to the question for your reference.

Comment: That accomplishes the same thing as having `class="expanded row"`, so I would say your way is the way to go.